# Take the value of a function

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
x = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < window.document.querySelectorAll('.btn[href*="/p"]').length; i++) {
        return window.document.querySelectorAll('.abtk[href*="/url"]')[i].href;
    }
};
```

I would like to have in x the results of the function and now the function in self when I test it in console in Chrome. How can I do it?

Comment: `x = (function() {})`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it [Immediate invoke function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), so the function gets executes immediately after defining. Below is the syntax for that

```
x = (function() {
    for (i = 0; i < window.document.querySelectorAll('.btn[href*="/p"]').length; i++) {
        return window.document.querySelectorAll('.abtk[href*="/url"]')[i].href;
    }
})();
```

Observe `()` at the end of function declaration.

Comment: It is because `return window.document.querySelectorAll('.abtk[href*="/url"]')[i].href;` the loop will run only one time. If you need the complete list, store the `querSelectorAll` result (i.e. by removing [i].href) and later loop over the elements for href. Also make sure there are more than one element in the document which is matching with the querSelector condition. Finally, I dont think there is need for Immediate invoke function here.  It has its own use case, but I feel its not suitable for this. Just use `for` loop, it should solve the problem.